# Bash how to copy the next value from csv

Tags: bash

i have this CSV file. how can i copy the first row and the next 2 values. **server.2=cl1z2** **server.3=cl1z3**. i want to repeat this task with the other Values. (e.g. third row and server.2=cl2z2 server.3=cl2z3 )

```
    z_name;z_hosts;z_clientPort;z_leaderPort;z_electionport;tickTime;initLimit;syncLimit;snapRetainCount;purgeInterval
cl1z1;server.1=cl1z1;2180;2890;3890;200;5;2;3;24
cl1z2;server.2=cl1z2;2181;2891;3891;200;5;2;3;24
cl1z3;server.3=cl1z3;2182;2892;3892;200;5;2;3;24
cl2z1;server.1=cl2z1;2183;2893;3893;200;5;2;3;24
cl2z2;server.2=cl2z2;2184;2894;3894;200;5;2;3;24
cl2z3;server.3=cl2z3;2185;2895;3895;200;5;2;3;24
```

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Please, add expected output  and some work done.

Comment: tickTime=200
#the directory where the Data_Log is stored
dataLogDir=/var/zokeeper/data/dataLog/stgt-cl1z1
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/var/zokeeper/data/snapshots/stgt-cl1z1
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2180
syncLimit=2
initLimit=5
server.1=cl1z1:2180:2890:3890
server.2=cl1z2:2181:2891:3891
server.3=cl1z3:2182:2892:3892
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0

Comment: while IFS=';' read z_name z_hosts z_clientPort z_leaderPort z_electionport tickTime initLimit syncLimit snapRetainCount purgeInterval
do
 if [ $line -gt 0 ]
 then

 
 konfiguration_zookeeper $z_name $z_clientPort $z_leaderPort $z_electionport $tickTime $initLimit $syncLimit $snapRetainCount $purgeInterval
 echo -ne '#######################   (100%)' $z_name
 sleep 1
 echo -ne '\n'
 fi
 line=$(($line +1))

done < $file
fi

Comment: As you can see, it does not fit in that comment box so well, so please edit the original question and add that to it.

Comment: function konfiguration_zookeeper()
{
 cd /home/r00t/Desktop/kafka/etc/kafka
 cp zookeeper.properties           zookeeper-${z_name}.properties
 sed -i  '/limitations./a tickTime='${tickTime}        zookeeper-${z_name}.properties
 sed -i  '/'${tickTime}'/a #the directory where the Data_Log is stored'     zookeeper-${z_name}.properties
   sed -i  's/tmp\/zookeeper/var\/keeper\/data\/snapshots\/'${z_name}'/g'     zookeeper-${z_name}.properties
 sed -i  '/Data_Log/a dataLogDir=/var\/keeper\/data\/dataLog\/'${z_name}     zookeeper-${z_name}.properties
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
result=""
while read line ; do 
  if echo "$line" | grep -q 'z_name'; then 
    result+="$line\n" 
  else 
    result+=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f2 | cut -d';' -f1)"\n" 
  fi  
done < your_csv_file
echo -e "$result"
```